# Group By column A OR B

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+---+
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
+---+---+
```

And I need to assign a non-unique identifier (ID) to each of the rows; this ID is shared by each row with a common value in either of the columns. So, row 1 will have the same ID as row 2, but it will also have the same ID as row 3 transitively through row 2 which has the same ID as row 3.

I have tried joining the table to itself and using RANK and DENSE_RANK functions to solve my problem but to no avail. I would post those queries here but they have been so inconsequential in helping my achieve my goal I can imagine they will only end up confusing people.

Please let me know any suggestions you may have.

Thanks!

Comment: You just want a composite key? I have no idea what you're asking. Your original question is about grouping but then you started asking about IDs. On top of that, you mention ID several times but you do not even have an ID column on the table so that's totally confusing me

Comment: @JoePhillips What I understood from OP is he wants to get groups of rows which have at least 1 value (A or B) in common. So with the data of the example, there will be only twp groups: 1) the first 4 rows and 2) the last row. Because only the last row has values which are not shared with any other row.

Comment: @James Please share your expected output of the query

Comment: Maybe this helps to ilustrate what I think OP wants https://pastebin.com/raw/v2t0gBJx CC @JoePhillips

Comment: This coudl cause the id to to change over time, Suppose you added a record 5, 6. It would create a new group. Then suppose a record 6,4 got added that would belong to the 4,4,  and the 5,6 group. which would mean that this would have to combine the two groups together. Is this really the intention?

Comment: I'd look into using a recursive CTE.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mentioning transitivity in your original problem description.  This already hints at the requirement to compute the *transitive hull* of the rows in the input table (two rows are related if they share their A or B values).  You thus need a recursive query to address your problem.

Here's one solution (SQL flavor: PostgreSQL).

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pairs;
CREATE TABLE pairs (A int, B int);

INSERT INTO pairs VALUES
  (1, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (2, 2),
  (2, 3),
  (4, 4);

WITH RECURSIVE hull(id, A, B) AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id, p.A, p.B
  FROM   pairs AS p

    UNION

  SELECT h.id, p.A, p.B
  FROM   hull AS h, pairs AS p
  WHERE  h.A IN (p.A, p.B) h.B IN (p.A, p.B)
)
SELECT MIN(h.id) AS id, h.A, h.B
FROM   hull AS h
GROUP  BY h.A, h.B;
```

Result:

```
┌────┬───┬───┐
│ id │ a │ b │
├────┼───┼───┤
│  1 │ 2 │ 2 │
│  1 │ 1 │ 1 │
│  5 │ 4 │ 4 │
│  1 │ 1 │ 2 │
│  1 │ 2 │ 3 │
└────┴───┴───┘
```

EDIT: Here is a variant that should run in SQL Server (no support for duplicate-eliminating `UNION` in recursive CTEs?):

```
DECLARE @rows int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pairs);

WITH hull(iter, id, A, B) AS (
  SELECT 0 AS iter, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.A, p.B) AS id, p.A, p.B
  FROM   pairs AS p

    UNION ALL

  SELECT h.iter + 1, h.id, p.A, p.B
  FROM   hull AS h, pairs AS p
  WHERE  (h.B IN (p.A, p.B) OR h.A in (p.A, p.B))
  AND    h.iter < @rows
)
SELECT MIN(h.id) AS id, h.A, h.B
FROM   hull AS h
GROUP  BY h.A, h.B;
```

Cheers,
  —Torsten

Comment: Good job detecting and answering the actual question :) (the question was for SQL Server though)

Comment: This is great! Thanks. I've come to realise it is probably not practical for my purposes of doing this on 500,000 records. Am I right in saying this process has a worst case time complexity of O(n^n)?

Comment: Oh, it’s not quite that bad. The above query (SQL Server variant) iterates a self-join of `pairs` *n* times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`lag()` window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to determine when both columns have changed.  A running sum over changes so far gives a group number:

```
select  A
,       B
,       sum(group_switch) over (order by A, B) as grp  -- Running sum
from    (
        select  case
                when lag(A) over (order by A, B) = A or
                     lag(B) over (order by A, B) = B then 0  -- Same group
                else 1  -- New group
                end as group_switch
        ,       *
        from    Table1
        ) sub
order by
        A
,       B
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/40f4f/5/0)

Comment: [I tried with other values](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/07fe6/1) and I think it should group `(5, 3), (4, 4), (5, 4)` togheter, but it's not working.

Comment: This breaks if you add a (5, 1) row to the table.   It should go to group 1, but it goes to group 3.   It breaks if any group has a gap in the cardinality of its members.

Comment: I think it's assuming data is in order. TBH SQL is probably not the best solution for this task

Comment: If the problem is sorting, isn't it possible to SORT BY A, B? Disclaimer: I reallly don't fully understand the answer code. cc @JoePhillips

Comment: @raul.vila The problem is that it needs to be sorted not by A or B but by GROUP (which we don't know yet because it hasn't been determined). It's really hairy and I can't imagine doing it efficiently in sql at all

Comment: Maybe this could work if you ordered by a derived column that always put the lower of the two numbers first.   (so the row 5,1 would be ordered by 1,5).  It might get tricky when you get into numbers greater than 9 though, and you have an order by over "1,21" vs "12,1" etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is that you have a bunch of sets and you want to give to all sets that intersect each other, even transitively, the same name.

So, for all (1,2),(1,3),(4,1) the same name is given, correct?

So what you should do is keep track of the super set for each group.

You can you use the values themselves as the id.

by rows
first row id is:
id 1

second row id is:
id 1_2

because there are rows with 1 already, those rows add the values of the current row to their id, and you get:

id 1_2
id 1_2

3rd row

id 2

because there are rows with 2 already, those rows add the values of the current row to themselves. Because they already have it, nothing happens:

results

id 1_2
id 1_2
id 1_2

then 
id 1_2
id 1_2
id 1_2
id 2_3

becomes:
then 
id 1_2_3
id 1_2_3
id 1_2_3
id 1_2_3

and finally

then 
id 1_2_3
id 1_2_3
id 1_2_3
id 1_2_4

Problem is, every time you are inserting something you must recalculate the id for all the current members.

If that is not an option, or you don't want the id to be pretty, don't change the id.

Give the initial row a random and big hash, then just find out if any existing row before the one you just inserted shares any value. If yes, give the new row the same hash. If no, generate new hash.

Maybe if you're gonna do intensive search, the first option is better, but if you are going to do intensive write, the second option is better.

Hope it helps. :)